# Trying to bit-bang TPIC6C595 shift register but no output

Tags: c, avr, shift-register

The code is for an AVR atamega168xplained mini board, with an ATmega168pb MCU. The shift register I am using is a Texas Instruments **TPIC6C595** I have the drain outputs of the shift register connected to the anodes of 8 LEDs. The OE(G) pin of shift register is tied to GND, and CLR tied to 5V. There is a 100nF ceramic capacitor between shift register VCC and GND. SER OUT is left unconnected to anything since I am trying to bit-bang just this one before I move up to chaining shift registers.

What happens is that I get no output from the shift register, all drain outputs are low (tested with multimeter). When I disconnect the SER IN, SRCK, and RCK from the microcontroller i get some flickering on only one of the LEDs which I guess is a result of those pins floating and being in an undefined state. I would have expected at least to get some kind of garbage output even if the code was wrong, but I get more of an output with the microcontroller completely disconnected. I know it is outputting a signal because I can connect it to the LEDS without the shift register and see they are lit up at various levels of intensity but do not have an oscilloscope to be able to actually look at the signals.

This is the code, with the defines for the output port at the top of the file included so it's clear what's being done:

```
#define DDR_SREG    DDRD
#define PORT_SREG   PORTD
#define SRCK        _BV(PORTD0)
#define RCK         _BV(PORTD1)
#define SER         _BV(PORTD2)

void display_write(uint8_t data)
{
    char i;

    PORT_SREG &= ~RCK;           // latch low

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        PORT_SREG &= ~SRCK;     // clock low
        if (data & 1)           // serial out
            PORT_SREG |= SER;
        else
            PORT_SREG &= ~SER;
        PORT_SREG |= SRCK;      // clock high
        data >>= 1;             // shift data
    }

    PORT_SREG |= RCK;           // latch high
}
```

Comment: If they are low, they are actually on. But if you apply clear to the output register, thy should be off actually. However, how did you measure? Are you aware that you need a pullup resistor or current source at the outputs to see any voltage? If not, you should read more about electronics - keyword "open drain" or "open collector"

Comment: Just read: "anodes?" You mean cathodes, right? The anodes whould be connected to Vcc (and there has to be a series resistor, of course!

Comment: The LEDs are connected common cathode, with the cathodes connected to ground, 330 ohm resistor on each LED anode, is this the problem, that the shift register can't actually source current? Sorry guys if this is really basic, I've done a little electronics stuff, but am trying to get into doing some more advanced things ... I'm also confused as to what should be done with CLR, should it be held high or low the datasheet says the input register is cleared when it is held low, and transfers data to the output buffer when high. So what's wrong with tying it to 5v?

Comment: Did you actually read the datasheet? I just had a peek and can tell you: it does not work. If the LEDs have really lit up, you might have a very bad connection and might have fried the device already. You shoudl learn about basic didital electronics first, before you try to connect an IC to an MCU. But don't worry, I fried my first ICs, too - at the age of 12.

Comment: "didital" LOL "di**g**ital", of course

Comment: Since this sounds more like a hardware question, I suspect it might be more appropriate at: http://electronics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. After doing some more research, it was apparent that this shift register has open drain outputs and cannot source current (they can only sink current). Adjusting the wiring accordingly I was able to get the shift register working to my satisfaction.